# Netbeans 8.2 Locking Up Frequently

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I have been using Netbeans64 8.2 for some time but I am now having issues with it regularly locking up.
Windows 10 Pro.

This is more often than not, when selecting an option from the Ctrl+space menu.

For example..

I have a File variable f.
I type "f.t" and get offered toString(), toURI() etc.
When I select the option to autofill any of the offered methods, Netbeans stops dead in its tracks.
"Downloading HTTP Javadoc" displayed on the bottom of the screen and progress indicator frozen.

Netbeans can only now be closed with Windows Task Manager.

I have tried clearing the cache as this seems to be the number #1 thing to do in the event that Netbeans freezes, but it has made no difference.

Many thanks if anybody could help throw some light on my problem.

I have taken the thread dump from the last crash but it is too large to publish here.
If anybody could tell me what I'm looking for specifically in the thread dump, that would be great.

Comment: Is there a reason your are using such an outdated version? Did you try NetBeans 12.x? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 8. I moved to NetBeans 10 some time ago and had issues with existing Java 8 projects so went back to 8.2. Thanks.